# Issue when saving files with Keynote

Tags: macos, icloud, keynote

Today I have run into issues with Keynote v5.3 (1170) running on MacOS X 10.8.5, all current updates installed. It is reproducible most of the time when saving documents in iCloud and sometime when saving documents to the local hard disk.

First, I get error messages of the form "Couldn’t save image". The images then disappear from the presentation slides and get replaced by gray frames, but they are still shown in the previews on the left hand side.

Second, an error of the form "The file has been changed by another application." occurs when saving. Keynote on my Mac was the only program accessing the file at that time.

Third, the issues seem to get worse whenever working with iCloud, but even when saving the file to the local hard disk there are still error messages every time I open the file. There seem to be some "temporary" folders on iCloud related to the file I'm working with (the name starting with the name of my file and ending with a random combination of characters). These folders contain a file named "index.key" of size zero.

If the temporary folders are any indication then it is possible that the error did not appear prior to my MacOS X 10.8.5 update since files accessed a couple of weeks ago and older do not show any problems.

**Update:** Other users have observed similar problems starting as early as August 2011, see [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3280572?start=0&tstart=0) and [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5185828?tstart=0). It seems that the problem has been around for some time now and that there is no fix in sight.

**Question:** Does anybody observe the same behavior and has a solution?